# Swap key values using bash (using awk/sed/anything)

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed

each line will print a column value and the values will look below:

```
key 1:value1,key 2:value2,key 3:value3
```

Note: the key is space separated...key 1...same goes with key3

I want to swap the key values using bash script (sed/awk/anything) and the desired output should look like below:

```
value1:key_1,value2:key2,value3:key_3
```

Comment: You want to replace spaces with `_` in the keys?

Comment: Typo at `key2`? Should it be `key_2`?

Answer (score 3):

You play with field and record separators in `gawk`:

```
gawk -F: '{print $2, $1}' RS=',|\n' ORS=',' OFS=: file
```

- `-F` set input field separator
- `OFS` output field separator
- `RS` input record separator
- `ORS` output record separator

---

Update, I missed the requirement to replace `key1` by `key_1` and so on. You can use the `sub` function for that:

```
awk -F: '{sub(/[[:digit:]]/, "_&", $2);print $2, $1}' RS=',|\n' ORS=',' OFS=: file
```

Comment: That wouldn't get output that op wants, they would all be on different lines.

Comment: @hek2mgl: i want the keys to be printed as key_1 ...i.e. replacing the space by _ ...look at the output..the result should not contain comma in the last key value pair

Comment: @hek2mgl: the key2 should be printed as is...not key_2

Comment: Your requirements are hard to get. Have you tried anything to solve the problem on your own?

Comment: Try: `awk -F: '{gsub(/[[:space:]]/,"",$1);gsub(/[[:digit:]]/,"_&", $1);var=(var""comma""$2":"$1);comma=","}END{print var}' RS=',|\n' <<< "key 1:value1,key 2:value2,key 3:value3"`

Answer (score 2):

With `sed`:

```
$ sed 's/\([^,:]*\):\([^,:]*\)/\2:\1/g' file
value1:key1,value2:key2,value3:key3
```

EDIT:

```
$ sed -e 's/\([^,:]*\):\([^,:]*\)/\2:\1/g' -e ':loop; s/\(:[^ ]*\) /\1_/g; t loop' file
value1:key_1,value2:key_2,value3:key_3
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another `sed` solution, straight forward -- replace the key space with an underscore then regex capture groups rearranging them in the substitution:

`sed 's/\(key \)\([0-9]\)/key_\2/g;s/\(key_[0-9]\)\(:\)\(value[0-9]\)\([,]*\)/\3\2\1\4/g' <<< "key 1:value1,key 2:value2,key 3:value3"`